# How to find what causes my notebook to crash?

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, crash, temperature

I have a new notebook and it crashes frequently.

```
$ uname -a
Linux bpgergo-notebook 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

I cannot specify any circumstance or application that is specific to the crash. I would like to find out the cause of the crash. I will describe how it looks like when it crashes and what I can see in the syslog. I would like you to tell me how to proceed with finding the cause.

### How it looks when it crashes

Sometimes it would freeze within one our of a restart, some other time within 2 days. E.g. when this latest freeze happened, after restart I just started some ordinary applications like a browser and a terminal, left it alone for an hour and when I got back to it, I noticed that it did not respond to anything. Not even to alt+ctl+F1. The only thing I can do at this point is to keep the power button pressed until it turns off.

When the freeze happens, I usually notice, that the notebook is a bit warmer then it should be. If I immediately restart and check `sensors` then I can see temperatures like 70 degrees Celsius which is not extreme but much higher then normal operation temp which is around 50.

### syslogs

I have checked the /var/log/syslog, this is what I found to be the latest log lines before it crashed.
chrash1:

```
Feb 10 15:01:39 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26093.242080] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x6013d4 0xffff5703 (0x1c408200)
Feb 10 15:01:39 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26093.242132] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x10ecc0 0xffffffff (0x1a40822c)
Feb 10 15:02:09 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26123.130129] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 15:02:09 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26123.130403] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
Feb 10 15:02:09 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26123.130407] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 15:02:11 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26124.445525] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x10ecc0 0xffffffff (0x1c40822c)
```

crash 2

```
Feb 10 16:17:58 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1088.808587] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x6013d4 0xffff5700 (0x1c408200)
Feb 10 16:18:23 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1113.486503] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 16:18:23 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1113.487291] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
Feb 10 16:18:23 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1113.487305] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.831356] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x122130 [ IBUS ]
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835021] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0xbad00100 0xbadf1002 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835247] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP4: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835252] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP6: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835257] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP7: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835262] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP9: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835267] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP11: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835271] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP12: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835276] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP13: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835281] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP15: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835286] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC8: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835293] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC20: 0x000000 0x00000000 (0x00000000)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835298] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC22: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835303] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC23: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835308] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC25: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835312] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC27: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.854481] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC28: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.877204] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC29: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.900634] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC31: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.992570] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x120058 [ IBUS TIMEOUT ]
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.072344] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078887] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP4: 0xbad00100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078904] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP6: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078910] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP7: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078917] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP9: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078923] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP11: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078939] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP12: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078945] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP13: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078950] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP15: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078954] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC8: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078960] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC20: 0x000000 0x00000000 (0x00000000)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078964] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC22: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078968] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC23: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078971] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC25: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078975] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC27: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078978] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC28: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078982] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC29: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078987] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC31: 0x000000 0x00000000 (0x00000000)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078997] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x120058 [ IBUS TIMEOUT ]
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.079008] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x136928 0xbadf1100 (0x19400200)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.079014] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP0: 0x10f904 0xffffffff (0x1e408201)
```

**Edit**

It was suggested that this may be related to graphics card.
I havent installed any driver or software related to the graphics card.
This is relevant part of the lspci result

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 18dd
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
Memory at eb000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at ec000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
Capabilities: [900] #19
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: If I can't find the cause, I think I will just install the LTS version and see if that crashes too.

Comment: Looks to be a graphics problem. Have you tried installing the proprietary nvidia drivers?

Comment: Also, does your notebook have Nvidia Optimus? If so, install [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) (on top of the prop drivers).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it may be a graphics problem. I have installed proprietary nvidia driver. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my question,

1. find out what is the program or package that is writing the last lines in the syslog before the crash
2. this a directory should be also checked: `/var/crash/`

As commenters pointed it out, nouveau is the open source nvidia driver.

Regarding the concrete problem, I had installed proprietary nvidia driver, since then I haven't had any more crash.

Answer (score 0):

Ibus: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus

In my case I had to unplug and plug in back my usb-keyboard and the freeze was over.

After upgrading all packages (sudo apt-get upgrade) it was resolved, so I have no clue what was wrong...